# Any ideas how to open/edit/export SDB Database files? (string database)

Tags: c#, database, string

With C#, the goal is to read/write data in to an SDB Database (String Database). Do you know any framework or simply ways to achieve this via C#?

Comment: From Visual Studio menu : Data : Add New Data Source : Database : Dataset : New Connection : Microsoft SQL Server Compact